# Switching tab makes CSS go crazy

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, 3d, css-animations

Can anyone explain why [this](http://www.fruitandashape.com/3d/) 3D works OK when you visit the page but disintegrates when you switch to another tab and then revert to the page?

[image]

But then...

[image]

... it disappears into the screen!

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body style='background-color: white; width: 900px;'>
        <div style='margin: 50px auto;'>
            <div id="img" style="background-image: url('img1.jpg'); width: 850px; height: 520px" />
        </div>
        <script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery-slide-show-filter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    width: 850px;
    height: 520px;

}

#img, #s1 {
            -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#cube{
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(-425px);
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    width: 850px;
    height: 520px;

}

#cube.enable
{
    -webkit-animation: flash 0.75s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: flash 0.75s ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation: flash 0.75s ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: flash 0.75s ease-in-out;
    animation: flash 0.75s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flash {
    100%   { -webkit-transform: translateZ(-425px) rotateY(90deg); }
}
```

Script:

```
var getImage = function(){
    var images = ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg"];


    $.each(images, function( index, value ) {
        $('<img />').attr('src', value);
    });

    index = 0;

    return function(){
        if (++index == images.length){
            index = 0;
        }

        return images[index];
    };
}();

setInterval(function(){
    transform($('#img'), getImage());
}, 1000);

function transform(img, newImg){

    img
        .wrap('<div id="container"><div id="cube"></div>')
        .css('-webkit-transform', 'translateZ(425px)');

    img
        .clone()
        .attr('id', 's1')
        .insertBefore(img)
        .css('background-image', 'url("' + newImg + '")')
        .css('position', 'absolute')
        .css('-webkit-transform', 'rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(425px)');

    PrefixedEvent($('#cube')[0], "AnimationEnd", function () {
        img.unwrap().unwrap();
        img.remove();
        $('#s1')
            .attr('id', 'img')
            .css('-webkit-transform', '');
    });

    $('#cube').addClass('enable');
}


function PrefixedEvent(element, type, callback) {
var pfx = ["webkit", "moz", "MS", "o", ""];
    for (var p = 0; p < pfx.length; p++) {
        if (!pfx[p]) type = type.toLowerCase();
        element.addEventListener(pfx[p]+type, callback, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the issue by calling `transform` only while the window has focus:

```
(function() {
  var inTab= false;
  $(window).blur(function() {
    inTab= false;
  });
  $(window).focus(function() {
    inTab= true;
  });
  setInterval(function() {
    if(inTab) {
      transform($('#img'), getImage());
    }
  }, 1000);
})();
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v28fjjnz/6/)

Click the image to simulate the window being focused.  You can then switch between tabs, and the animation will no longer break.

Comment: But why is it able to call transform when the window is not in focus but not able to handle the AnimationEnd event?

Comment: Really good question.  It may be that the timer intervals are buffered when the tab is inactive, but animationend is not, causing everything to go out of sync.  I'll do some more research.

Comment: This doesn't entirely fix the problem though. For example on the iphone it doesn't seem possible to focus the element and thus start the animation.

Comment: I initialized `inTab` to false for the fiddle, but you should initialize it as true on your site.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because if you switch tab the `AnimationEnd` event doesn't fire so there's no clean up.